# QxOrm how to map the class name and table name

Tags: qxorm

Use `QxOrm`, is there a way to name the table name?
For example,I have a class named `ClassA`.
And I want to `ClassA` is corresponding a table named `table_a` in the database.
How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer.
in qx::register_class() method, use :
`t.setName("table_a");`